# Option to remove distracting click-bait

Tags: feature-request

I would like to remove the 'Hot Network Questions' section from SO, or have an option to remove it from my view of SO

Can we have a Preference option to hide this set of links, or put the links into an expander (and remember my setting)

Maybe replace it with static adverts if you really need to fill the space.

Yes people have asked similar questions, but I feel the need to raise this with the SO designers again to get them to reconsider removing/hiding this irrelevant section.

Comment: A critical aspect of a [meta-tag:feature-request] is an explanation of _why_ the feature is requested and why it would be an improvement to the site. That seems to be missing here.

Comment: Wasn't there a user script to hide Hot Network Questions?

Comment: `an explanation of why the feature is requested` "Hot network questions" has zero relevance to the mission of Stack Overflow, which is to provide answers to programming questions. Its only goal is to increase engagement with the rest of the network. The "lol if it distracts you just don't click on the links" argument is about the same quality as "if you don't like my low quality question just ignore it". At workplaces with strict Internet usage policies, it could sabotage Stack Overflow getting greenlighted as a work tool. Asking to be able to turn it off seems more than justified.

Comment: if you have chrome, get stylebot plugin and add the following rule to the css: `#hot-network-questions { 
    display:none;
}`

Comment: @Tschallacka That's not entirely true. Votes in meta can reflect agreement/disagreement, but they are also cast to signal a question quality/usefulness.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/q/6091/31042). It'll hide the hot network questions by default although you can customize to hide whatever you want

[image: sox]

There are more ways to hide it that you can find in [How to avoid "Hot Network Questions" on the sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222721/230282), for example use either of the below filters if you're using an ad-blocker

```
stackoverflow.com###hot-network-questions
###hot-network-questions
```